# Removing backslash followed by any char other than a quote from string

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm getting JSON data from curl in R, but the data comes in form of string, which is then converted to dataframe in jsonlite.

The data entries start with the symbol " , but sometimes there is a backslash in a variable preventing the conversion.

How can I remove every occurrence of \ not followed by quote symbol "?
Example: I could remove the occurrences of '\o' by using the following code:

```
gsub('\\\\o','o',myString)
```

But I need some way to apply this to every character that is not a quote symbol.

Comment: What if the backslash at the end of the string? Or is this scenario out of scope? You might use `gsub("\\\\(?!\")", "", x, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: In my case it cannot happen, but this is useful in other situations.

Comment: How about replace `\\+(?!")` with nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write just what you said.  Backslash followed by anything other than a double-quote

```
gsub("\\\\([^\\"])", "\\1", myString)
```

Comment: This worked with a minor edit gsub('\\\\([^\\"])', "\\1", myString)